# Android youtube custom subscribe button

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, google-signin

I making android app in which user can see YouTube channel and they can subscribe to particular channel. When user opens a video in my app there is a custom button for subscribing.
I have done the authentication part like first user have to do google log in to use my app and it is working successfully. 
With some research I found this code for subscribe button.

```
List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

    try {
        // Authorize the request.
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "addsubscription");

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                "youtube-cmdline-addsubscription-sample").build();
```

It is showing cannot resolve method
 'authorize.(java.util.List,java.lang.String)' 
 Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.